# How to push custom data to a WooCommerce cart item?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been scrambling my head for hours so maybe one of you can help...

I want to push custom data to a WooCommerce cart item from a non-product page.

[This](https://woocommerce-842277-3644151.cloudwaysapps.com/) is my current webpage to get a basic function working.

These steps will point to the custom data that needs to be added to a cart item;

1. Click on the product and add it to your cart
2. You will be redirected to a page with an image and coordinates following your cursor, click somewhere on the image and you'll see the coordinates change in the right hand side list.
3. The cars you see in the list are cart items that you have in your cart currently and the coordinates is the custom data that needs to added to the cart item

Can this be done with an AJAX function so that after every click the custom data is pushed to said cart item?

Any help is appreciated!